# How to Increase page loading speed in Zend Framework Application

Tags: performance, zend-framework, loading

I have developed application using ZF.The app is little big with a lots of features.

I use Zend_Application(already using autoloader in constructor),Zend_Layout,Zend_view,Zend_form,etc. My current issue is, the page loading is very slow and that too in localhost with XAMP.

I have enabled xdebug, to investigate the issue, got a cachegrind file in "tmp" folder and tried to view it with WinCachegrind software. There i can a see a lot of processes and functions being run for each and every request or page load.

Also, i have installed YSlow add-on for firefox and observed the speed of page loads in seconds...I have compare the speed with ZF and non ZF applications. And from the comparison, the pages for non zf app takes less than 1 sec to load and for the ZF app, it takes atleast 6-7 seconds. What a huge difference.

Main Things happen in the app are :

1) Database connection happens for each request.

2) Im not adding the view to layout explicitly,ZF just appends it automatically, to layout.phtml, based on the action name.

3) Some windows have forms with few drop down boxes which fetches data from the database.

4) Have menus with ACL implimented, before it was loading the privilges from DB for each and every request, but now i have optimized it, so that it will work only duiring the login and rest of the time it will take from the Zend_Registry.

I would like to attach the cachegrind file so that some one can see whats happening in the background, but i cant see an option here for attaching.

Someone please help me to find a solution for this. Any kind of help is really appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: Do you know how much of the load time is spent performing database queries? Take a look at the DB profiler - http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.profiler.html

Comment: Can you link to the cachegrind file somewhere? Or even a screenshot to give people an overview. Otherwise there isn't any way we can tell what the real problem is.

Comment: yeah sure..ill upload it somewhere...annd will give you the link..

Comment: @tim i have triggered ther zend_db_profiler results to the firebug as well...there are queries with placeholders and other required queries for the pages...all together some less than 1 ms...for most of the pages...

Comment: @Ryan Here is the link to the cachegrind file http://southkeralaprovinceocd.com/cachegrind.out.2904

Comment: Also please find the screenshot of the callgrind software results...

Comment: http://southkeralaprovinceocd.com/callgrin1.jpg                       http://southkeralaprovinceocd.com/callgrin2.jpg  http://southkeralaprovinceocd.com/callgrin3.jpg http://southkeralaprovinceocd.com/callgrin4.jpg

Comment: Also please find the screenshot of the callgrind software results...

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to give some hints.

First **database connection should happen only once** (except if you use several privileges access on the database or several databases). So check that you use Singleton patterns with you Zend_Db_Tables object

Then you do not use **Zend_Cache**. You should really start to use Zend_Cache and build several cache objects. Let's say for example a File cach, with long term storage, and a memcache or Apc Cache, storing objects. Then use these cache  in several layers:

- gives the FileCache to Zend_Db_Table (defaultMetaDataCache), this way you will avoid a loot of metadata queries, queries that ask for description of each columns of the tables you use.
- Store one or more Acl object (depends on how you use Acl, if you have one big Acl with all rules or several with subsets). And store them in mid-duration caches when they are built.
- Think of other usages, detect heavy loops, semi-static contents (like you select lists, how many time should they be considered static?)

Finally, get a whole mental image of how your application engine works, and how your data will grow and be used.You will need that step to use application levels caches in the very best way (for example should some elements be cached for groups of users?, should Acl objects be build for groups, for each user, for everybody, is ther some blocks in the layout that should be rendered the same for everybody?).

Comment: hi regilero, thank you very much for your answer. First of all, the app will work under a vpn, where there wont be many users online at the same time..its not open for public. So we can guess the limit of users. Second, some of the tables in the DB will grow huge on the go.Also, ACL, once a user is logged in, they will have certain menus,  that can access, but also, they will not have access to certain link under a menu which they are allowed access..so the app structure goes like that...and if there is cache for some pages, mainly with forms, cache can be very usefull. What about eAccelerator

Comment: I'm talking about using cache in your application, for objects loaded by your application, not only about caching final pages. For example you build an ACL object for each user with all his rules, and cahe this object to avoid rebuilding it each time. For the Opcode look at APC, as it will provide you with a cache backend as well.

Comment: Hi regilero,ok...Im planning for caching the objects as you said...will check out the performance difference. Also, according to you what all the other areas that i need to check...sometimes i can see a lag in the view rendering. Your information was helpful. And, hope you have seen the cachegrind file...there are lots of functions being called...which makes me more worried...anyway let me try with the caching techniques. Zend_Cache would be the correct choice right...

Comment: Yes I saw the cachegrind, and this make me think you do not have any BIG problem, but a lot of calls in a lot of layers, so by using caches you will avoid the rebuild of a lot of these calls. The view rendering lags are sometimes due to Zend Form, forms with a lot of form elements (around 50-100) can be very long, from my experience because of decorators plugins management, think about ViewScript helper for big forms.